# Issue with Xcode in Main.Storyboard

Tags: xcode

I've been working on a project the last few weeks in Xcode and everything's been great. Main.Storyboard all of a sudden, will not load or open. Other projects open fine. There hasn't been any significant changes in this project. The last thing I tried doing was adding a navigation bar to one of my view controllers, to add buttons or items. I also tried adding a navigation item. Things started to complicate after trying to do these things. I have the latest version of Xcode, my project settings are linked correctly and tried rebooting my Mac but it doesn't solve anything. Does anybody know what may have caused this error and how to resolve?

Comment: Is the project under some kind of SCM? Git perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The easy way:

Check out the latest *working* version of the storyboard file and try the changes again. Likely something odd and transient happened that corrupted the existing storyboard file (I've seen it happen with managed object model files before which are also XML underneath).

## If there are too many changes to redo them:

Make a copy of the current storyboard file outside the repo and then checkout the latest working version of the file from the repo.

Diff the two files moving over changes that make sense from the troublesome file keeping an eye out for balanced tags (i.e. if a view has an opening tag but no closing tag Xcode will get confused).
Try opening the modified storyboard in Xcode. With luck it will open and be fine. Otherwise you will need to do a bit more digging or go back to option one and redo the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your repo and I can open *Main.storyboard* just fine:

[image]